# algebraic multiplicity of eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a problem with the following question:
Consider the nxn matrix A=[1 1 1 ... 1; 1 1 1 ... 1; ...; 1 1 1 ...1] (all elements are 1). Show that 0 is an eigenvalue, with algebraic multipicity n-1.

I know that 0 is eigenvalue, b/c columns are linearly dependent, and matrix is non-invertible. *But how to show that its algebraic multiplicity is **n-1**?*

Thank you!

Comment: Why not calculate $\mathrm{det}|\lambda I_n-A|$, it's easy.

Comment: I think it is quiet complicated, or maybe you know easier way than I do? If it is so, can you, plase, explain it more detailed? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the process  of calculating $\mathrm{det}|\lambda I_n-A|$. As the matrix is not convenient to type by LaTeX, I just give a picture. I'm so sorry about this.[image: aha]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This perfectly makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The algebraic multiplicity can't be less than the geometric multiplicity, which is $n-1$ because all vectors orthogonal to $(1,\ldots,1)$ are in the null space.

Comment: Thank you! But we haven't covered orthogonality yet. So, is there any other way to prove it? I thought dim(NullA) is n-1, because there is only one lin.independent column, then geom.multiplicity is n-1. As alg.multiplicity is greater than or equal to geom.multiplicity, it also would be n-1. Am I right?